# infinite scroll & colorbox after loading new images

Tags: jquery, colorbox, infinite-scroll

When my infinite scroll loads new images, the colorbox call on that new images isn't working anymore. How can I make it work that the colorbox will work after loading new content through the infinite scroll call?

infinite-scroll (+ masonry):

```
$(function(){

var $container = $('#content_home');

$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '.wrdLatest',
     columnWidth:15
  });
});

$container.infinitescroll({
  navSelector  : '#nav',    
  nextSelector : '#nav a', 
  itemSelector : '.wrdLatest'  
  },
  function( newElements ) {
    var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
        $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
    });
  }
);

});
```

colorbox call:

```
 $(function() {
    $(".item_popup").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"916", height:"838"});
 });
```

html:

```
    <div class="wrdLatest" id="<?=$row['item_id']?>">
         <a class="item_popup" href="popup.php?id=<?=$row['item_id']?>">click</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: `var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });` what is this?

Answer (score 0):

solved it by adding the colorbox call to the infinite scroll callback:

```
  navSelector  : '#nav',    
  nextSelector : '#nav a', 
  itemSelector : '.wrdLatest'  
  },
  function( newElements ) {
    var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
        $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
        $(".item_popup").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"916", height:"838"});
        //$(".item_popup").colorbox({onComplete:function(){ $("#cboxWrapper").append("<div id='textbox12'>hello world</div>"); } }); 
        $("#item_popup").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"916", height:"838"});
        $(".signup_popup").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"488", height:"279", href:"welcome.php", scrolling: false});
        $(".activate_popup").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"488", height:"279", href:"active.php", scrolling: false});
        $("#activate_popup").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"488", height:"279", href:"active.php", scrolling: false});
        $(".signup_popup1").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"488", height:"279", href:"welcome.php", scrolling: false});
    });
  }
);
```